# How to pull two intervals out of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

```
@photos = @user.photos[0..2, 4..6] if @user.avatar == 3
```

this syntax doesn't seem to be working. Can I not put many arguments into an array like [1,2,3,4]? or [1, 4..6]?

for some reason i get an error can't convert range into integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby does not allow you to pass more than one argument to [] if the argument is a range.

You could use this ugly thing here:

```
@photos = @user.photos
@photos = @photos[0..2] + @photos[4..6] if @user.avatar == 3
```

But you'd better use:

```
@photos = @user.photos
@photos.delete_at 3
```

to remove the 3rd element.

Cheers,

Comment: I had to end up using both of the above techniques for different cases, saved me some time. Also I couldn't add [2] + [4..6] I had to write [2..2] + [4..6]. syntax is strange but i had to add an interval to an interval

Comment: That's because [2] returns an element of the array, whilst [4..6] returns an array.